# Best way to validate multiple conditions on JSON or objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting a POST Request with a questionnaire with 5 different chapters, I need to take this questionnaire and make like 45 validations with different Props of the JSON, the validations examples are:

- Prop A + Field B should be equal to Prop C.
- Prop E should be Empty if Prop D is equal to 3.
- If Prop F is greater than 20 then Prop G should be empty.

And so on, the point here is that I can do this validations in many if-else statements but I want to know if there is better way to the validations.

Comment: Did you read the [Model validation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: It would be great if you could share yourr real scenario where you are you struggling with, so that it would be easier to assist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we're talking about ASP.NET WebApis in here, and if we do, you shouldn't really be receiving any "JSON" in your controllers. What you should do is, to create a Class that has all the properties the json you want to receive have.

For example, if we have a controller such as the "LoginController", and inside it we have a Post method that we use to authenticate our users, how do you think we would be able to receive, in json, an object to check for what exactly did the user enter in the authentication process?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    // {"username": "john_doe", "password": "P4$$w0rd"}
    public async Task Login(LoginDto loginDto)
    {
        // Validation and authentication logic...
        if (loginDto.Password != "Hackerman")
            return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Where LoginDto class has only two parameters:

```
public class LoginDto
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now that it is settled how exactly you should receive your "json", in order to validate, you can write manual validations in the domain layer of your api, depending on the validation. Or you can use tools such as [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) that provides you and the user an amazing experience on validating inputs.